# 17.10 workspaces, xdotool, and wmctrl

Tags: workspaces, xdotool, wmctrl

Under (not-yet-installed) 17.10, I want a fixed number of
 (not dynamic) workspaces; whether they're presented
 horizontally or vertically I don't care. Under Ubuntu 16.10
 I'm running now, I had do a system-settings tweak to enable
 multiple workspaces; then, a couple of `gsettings` commands to
 set the multiple-workspace grid size. But they worked on
 Unity, and Unity is gone. To select a workspace, I wrote a
 shellism that uses `xdotool mousemove` and `xdotool click`,
 under Ubuntu 16.10. When I ran Ubuntu 17.10 from the DVD, it
 couldn't install either `xdotool` or `wmctrl`.

Can I get the same workspace capability under Ubuntu 17.10?
 And, `xdotool` and `wmctrl` (or something else that does the
 same things)? I'll fix my shell file to do whatever it has
 to, for Ubuntu 17.10 (which it can detect by uname -r), but
 except for things I do once, after installation, I don't
 want to have to do anything with my fingers.

Comment: the obvious: 16.10 is EOL & insecure as its not patched - please upgrade.  I downloaded & installed `wmctrl` (using only `sudo apt install wmctrl`) on Ubuntu 17.10 & it works normally (it was only tested with xorg login).  I don't use `xdotool`, but it offered to be installed (with `libxdo3` as req)

Comment: The default login on Ubuntu 17.10 is Wayland. `xdotool` and `wmctrl` won't work properly or at all in Wayland. You'll need to login to an Xorg session.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed `wmctrl` normally on Ubuntu 17.10 with no issues using

`sudo apt install wmctrl`

I tested it (using xorg) and it worked normally.  (I use `wmctrl` on other machines)

I also `sudo apt install xdotool` and it offered to install (along with `libxdo3` as a requirement) without any errors. The 'x' in the name implies to me it'll need xorg (not wayland) but I'd expect it to work too (I'm not familiar with this so I didn't install or test).

A few clicks (with tweak tool) and I had a static number of workspaces instead of the dynamic default, so you shouldn't have an issue.

Unity runs on 17.10 - but Unity is no longer a default, nor supported by Canonical; it's now a community project (like xubuntu, ubuntu-mate ...), and is being tested for 18.04 along with other DEsktops. Unity is NOT gone.